# Get lines from file that match strings in another file using AWK

Tags: csv, hash, awk, key

I have file named `key` and another csv file named `val.csv`. As you can imagine, the file named `key` looks something like this:

```
123
012
456
```

The file named `val.csv` has multiple columns and corresponding values. It looks like this:

```
V1,V2,V3,KEY,V5,V6
1,2,3,012,X,t
9,0,0,452,K,p
1,2,2,000,L,x
```

I would like get the subset of lines from `val.csv` whose value in the KEY column matches the values in the `KEY` file. Using the above example, I would like to get an output like this:

```
V1,V2,V3,KEY,V5,V6
1,2,3,012,X,t
```

Obviously these are just toy examples. The real `KEY` file I am using has nearly 500,000 'keys' and the `val.csv` file has close to 5 million lines in them. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk -F, 'FNR==NR{k[$1]=1;next;} FNR==1 || k[$4]' key val.csv 
V1,V2,V3,KEY,V5,V6
1,2,3,012,X,t
```

#### How it works

- `FNR==NR { k[$1]=1;next; }`

  This saves the values of all keys read from the first file, `key`.

  The condition is `FNR==NR`.  `FNR` is the number of lines read so far from the current file and `NR` is the total number of lines read.  Thus, if `FNR==NR`, we are still reading the first file.

  When reading the first file, `key`, this saves the value of key in associative array `k`.  This then skips the rest of the commands and starts over on the `next` line.
- `FNR==1 || k[$4]`

  If we get here, we are working on the second file.

  This condition is true either for the first line of the file, `FNR==1`, or for lines whose fourth field is in array `k`.  If the condition is true, awk performs the default action which is to print the line.